# MPPlayableContentDataSource doesn't call contentItemForIdentifier:completionHandler:

Tags: ios, carplay

I'm working with CarPlay(simulator 10.3.1) and implement all methods in MPPlayableContentDataSource but method below isn't called.

```
- (void)contentItemForIdentifier:(NSString *)identifier completionHandler:(void(^)(MPContentItem *__nullable, NSError * __nullable))completionHandler
```

Does anybody know any reasons?

Comment: maybe there are 0 items in some numberOfItems method? or maybe you have no identifiers registered

Comment: all other methods are called. I have identifiers

Comment: Documentation says `A block that is called after the content item has been loaded.` So I'm guessing your content item does not load

Comment: Items loaded but method isn't called. all other methods are called they enough to fill information.

Answer (score 0):

Have you set delegate & dataSource of the MPPlayableContentDataSource. Because without setting this two property, all methods related to dataSource & delegate won't execute.

Comment: Method in question is optional and it doesn't work for me. All other methods work. it's dataSource. But doesn't matter - content is loaded and displayed on CarPlay. I need this method for other reasons

Comment: Method you have listed is inherited from "MPPlayableContentDataSource" Protocol. So if you are not inheriting that protocol to that class, the method you defining will work like other methods we use. That means it won't execute until you call it. So just cross check whether you have inherited this protocol when class is defined. For reference you can go through this link https://developer.apple.com/documentation/mediaplayer/mpplayablecontentdatasource?language=objc

Comment: All other methods work. My class conform MPPlayableContentDataSource Protocol.

Answer (score 0):

`numberOfChildItemsAtIndexPath:` and `contentItemAtIndexPath:` is the synchronous API that is usually used.

From my understanding, CarPlay only uses `contentItemForIdentifier:completionHandler:` when you are triggering the asynchronous loading via `beginLoadingChildItemsAtIndexPath:completionHandler`.

FWIW, the official CarPlay audio programming guide as of March 2017 (I didn't see a newer version, at least not online) does not mention the asynchronous methods.

Comment: Hi. Can you please help me on this question -https://stackoverflow.com/q/59501929/472336