# Lazy Loading Data in iOS Carplay

Tags: ios, swift, ios13, carplay

How to lazy load the items while the user scrolling in Carplay ?

I am using beginLoadingChildItems from MPPlayableContentDataSource to load the first set of items but how I can call the next page when a user scrolls to the bottom of the page?

[image]

Comment: I am facing one more problem here - playableContentManager?.reloadData() never works. When I am adding items to the list & calling this function nothing happens.

Comment: follow this https://github.com/pronebird/UIScrollView-InfiniteScroll

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The way you can achieve this is inside the following function:

```
func beginLoadingChildItems(at indexPath: IndexPath, completionHandler: @escaping (Error?) -> Void)
```

As Example:

```
if (indexPath[componentIndex] + 1) % Threshold == 0 { // Threshold is Your Defined Batch Size

    // Load the next corresponding batch 

}
```

Load your lazy data, then call:

```
completionHandler(nil) // In case of no error has occurred
```

,but firstly, you need to return the total items count correctly in the following function:

```
func numberOfChildItems(at indexPath: IndexPath) -> Int
```

---

Something like the below,

```
class YourDataSource : MPPlayableContentDataSource {

    private var items = [MPContentItem]()
    private var currentBatch = 0

    func beginLoadingChildItems(at indexPath: IndexPath, completionHandler: @escaping (Error?) -> Void) {

        // indexPath[1]: is current list level, as per CarPlay list indexing (It's an array of the indices as ex: indexPath = [0,1] means Index 0 in the first level and index 1 at the second level).
        // % 8: Means each 8 items, I will perform the corresponding action.
       // currentBatch + 1 == nextBatch, This check in order to ensure that you load the batches in their sequences.

        let currentCount = indexPath[1] + 1

        let nextBatch = (currentCount / 8) + 1

        if currentCount % 8 == 0 && currentBatch + 1 == nextBatch { 

            // Load the next corresponding batch 
            YourAPIHandler.asyncCall { newItems in

                self.currentBatch = self.currentBatch + 1

                items.append(newItems)

                completionHandler(nil)

                MPPlayableContentManager.shared().reloadData()

            }

        } else {

            completionHandler(nil)

        }


    }

}

func numberOfChildItems(at indexPath: IndexPath) -> Int {

    return self.items.count

}
```

Comment: Hi, Thank you for your reply.  Can you please tell what should I return total number of items as there can be infinite items and what is componentIndex in indexPath[componentIndex]? Please reply

Comment: I want to load 8 items in single page & when user scrolls to last item load next 8 items

Comment: Can you check the updated answer, I have tried to add an example for illustration.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, in my code issue was, last item in the list we have to declare as a container, then only beginLoadingChildItems delegate gets called. That was missing in my code.

Comment: Best of Luck 

Answer (score 2):

CarPlay does not support infinite scrolling by default.  There is no callback when the last item on the list is displayed.  However, the solution by @amr-el-sayed is an interesting one, since CarPlay will preload categories when they first appear on the screen.  Thus, if the last item on the list is a category, CarPlay will call `beginLoadingChildItemsAtIndexPath` with the indexpath of the last item on the list, which could be used to simulate infinite scrolling.  In that case, it becomes necessary to call `MPPlayableContentManager reloadData` because the preload is actually being called for the nested category (which is not displayed), rather than the category for which you are trying to implement infinite scrolling.  This can result in some flash, as CarPlay must now redraw the entire UI.  If possible, a better solution is simply to load a long list of items initially.  Note that CarPlay will enforce a limit of [`enforcedContentItemsCount`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/mediaplayer/mpplayablecontentmanagercontext/1623568-enforcedcontentitemscount?language=objc) when [MPPlayableContentManager.contentLimitsEnforced](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/mediaplayer/mpplayablecontentmanagercontext/1623570-contentlimitsenforced?language=objc) is true, for example, when a vehicle is in motion.

Answer (score 0):

Key here is to declare your MPContentItem as a container like this

```
            let item = MPContentItem(identifier: "Tab \(indexPath)")
            item.isContainer = true
            item.isPlayable = false
            return item
```

Then only the framework will call beginLoadingChildItems method when that item is visible on the screen.

Inside beginLoadingChildItems call the load more function and refresh the items using

```
playableContentManager?.reloadData()
```

function